# Is there an order in which models are generated into database?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my project I need to change the location where files are being uploaded. This is done using a FileSystemStorage. The path were the files are uploaded should be easy to configure, for example using the Django Admin.

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage  
from django.db import models  

class Setting(models.Model):  
    entry = models.CharField(primary_key=True, db_column="entry", max_length=50)  
    value = models.CharField(db_column="value", max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" %(self.entry)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'settings'
        verbose_name = 'Setting'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Settings'    

fs =  FileSystemStorage(location=Setting.objects.get(entry__exact='upload_path').value)      

def generate_filename(instance, filename):  
    ...

class FileImport(models.Model):
    data_file = models.FileField(_('Data file'), upload_to=generate_filename, storage=fs)
```

I receive this error:

django.db.utils.DatabaseError:
 relation "settings" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ELECT "settings"."entry", "settings"."value" FROM "settings"...

for the line where FileSystemStorage is being created. Is there a way of telling Django to create table settings(for Setting objects) first and then fill this table with some fixtures?

Answer (score 0):

That won't solve your problem, since the `Settings` table still won't be populated. Move it into a class attribute that gets initialized the first time it's instantiated.

Comment: Can you give me a little example on how to do this?

Comment: I was thinking of giving None as value for location at the beginning and then after the settings values are in the database to return exactly that value.

Comment: I've wrote the following code, but still no succes:class DefaultSetting(object):
    fs = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        if self.__class__.fs is None:
            self.__class__.fs = FileSystemStorage(location = Setting.objects.get(entry__exact='upload_path').value)

class FileImport(models.Model):
    data_file = models.FileField(_('Data file'), upload_to=generate_filename, storage=DefaultSetting().fs)